# How to show different menu on sidebar for each page in django?

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates

I have 2 navigation bar, one is in the top and the second is in the side. In my top navbar, I have 3 different menu, namely "Dashboard", "Manage" and "Report". I want it to display different items in my sidebar when clicking one the menu in my top navbar.

Something like this:

In my "Dashboard" (the Dashboard in the top navbar will get highlighted) and will display the following on my sidebar:

```
- dashboard-item-no1
- dashboard-item-no2
- dashboard-item-no3
```

In my "Manage" (the Manage in the top navbar will get highlighted) and will display the following on my sidebar:

```
- manage-item-no1
- manage-item-no2
- manage-item-no3
```

In my "Report" (the Report in the top navbar will get highlighted) and will display the following on my sidebar:

```
- report-item-no1
- report-item-no2
- report-item-no3
```

Can anyone please help me?
I saw similar problem but it's in php and not django so I've been stuck with this problem for almost a week by now :'(

Comment: from your question it is not clear if you want to load a new page with the right side menu from server (django topic) or if you want to update dynamically the menu in the browser on the client side without loading a new page (javascript topic)

Comment: Thank you for replying @Razenstein! I want it to load in a new page with the right side menu from the server. I'm so sorry for my unclear question. Hope you can help me...

Comment: depends somehow on the overall modular structure of your html pages. A very simple way would just be to add the menu text and links to the context that you hand over from the django view to the template render function. Or to hardcode it in individual sub-html files and use the django "extends" feature to link them to a base html. Without any code it is difficult to give advise as the context of your question is not quite defined.